# Application Crashes At [context save:&error] (after deleting a record)

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am facing a weird problem where my application get crashes when delete a record an after that call [context save:&error] method. I get this problem randomly and when it happens, I see no exception on console.

Regards
Muhammed Aamir

Comment: can you please expand your question with detailed information about the reported error, relevant snippets of your code, and any additional information that might be useful to provide you with a meaningful answer? (e.g, how do you 'delete a record' ?)

Comment: how is the error handled? The core-data template from apple uses abort();. Which will lead to a "crash". NSLog more details of the error with `[error userInfo]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface file

```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

In Implementations File

```
     @synthesize fetchedResultsController=__fetchedResultsController;
     @synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;
    - (void)dealloc
    {
[__managedObjectContext release];
    [__fetchedResultsController release];
    [super dealloc];
    }
```

Use this code for delete in a tableview

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
    [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```